# PSTricks lines not shown in the rightmost quarter of a page

Tags: pstricks

I use XeLaTeX to compile. But I can not figure out why the problem described in the title occurs. It looks like something covers the rightmost quarter, but words put by \rput alike will show.

Let me describe it in more detail.

I was typesetting a two-column document, in which a small pspicture was included as following codes:

```
    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
        %\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=7pt](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
        \psset{linecolor=purple}
        \psframe[](-2,-2)(2,2)
        \psline[linestyle=dashed]{-}(-2,0)(2,0)
        \psline[linestyle=dashed]{-}(0,-2)(0,2)

        \rput{0}(-1,-1){\Large(A)}
        \rput{0}(1,-1){\Large(B)}
        \rput{0}(-1,1){\Large(C)}
        \rput{0}(1,1){\Large(D)}

        \rput{0}(-2.5,1.5){4}\rput{0}(-2.5,.5){3}\rput{0}(-2.5,-.5){2}\rput{0}(-2.5,-1.5){1}
        \rput{90}(-3.5,0){\shortstack[c]{风险\\（气流受限的GOLD分级）}}

        \rput{0}(-1,-2.5){CAT$ < $10}\rput{0}(1,-2.5){CAT$ \geqslant $10}
        \rput{0}(0,-3){\color{red}症状}
        \rput{0}(-1,-3.5){mMRC~0-1}\rput{0}(1,-3.5){mMRC$ \geqslant $2}
        \rput{0}(0,-4){\color{red}呼吸困难}

        \rput{0}(3,1){\scriptsize\shortstack[l]{$ \geqslant $2急性加重史\\或\\\textcolor{red}{$ \geqslant $1因急性}\\\textcolor{red}{加重住院}}}
        \rput{0}(3,-1){\scriptsize\shortstack[l]{$ \leqslant $1急性加重史\\且\\\textcolor{red}{未因急性}\\\textcolor{red}{加重住院}}}

        \rput[t]{90}(4,0){\shortstack{风险\\（急性加重史）}}

        \rput[t]{0}(0,3){慢阻肺综合评估(GOLD 2015)}
    \end{pspicture}
```

When I put it in the left column, it appeared what I wanted:[image]

However when I put it in the right, it started to behave strangely:[image]

BTW, it occurred to me that several months ago I used *mdframed* package, which involved a choice of *framemethod*. Still, when you set the method to be PSTricks, the rightmost part (1/4) of a frame generating from the mdframed was missing, too.

When the method was Tikz, the frame would be complete.

Comment: I think we need your minimized code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have no problem with your example!